# Get table_schema, Table_name and total number of columns from information_schema in mysql

Tags: mysql, information-schema

I need to get table_schema, Table_name and total number of columns from information_schema in mysql (In short all the table names, with no.of columns each table is having in all schemas).
Let me know if there someone is having handy.

```
SELECT CONCAT(t.TABLE_SCHEMA, '.', t.TABLE_NAME) as entity, count(c.COLUMN_NAME)
FROM information_schema.TABLES t JOIN information_schema.STATISTICS s on
s.TABLE_CATALOG = t.TABLE_CATALOG
AND s.TABLE_SCHEMA = t.TABLE_SCHEMA
AND s.TABLE_NAME = t.TABLE_NAME
AND s.INDEX_NAME  = 'PRIMARY'
AND s.COLUMN_NAME = 'PK'
AND s.SEQ_IN_INDEX  = 1
JOIN information_schema.`COLUMNS` c on
c.TABLE_CATALOG = t.TABLE_CATALOG
AND c.TABLE_SCHEMA = t.TABLE_SCHEMA
AND c.TABLE_NAME = t.TABLE_NAME
AND c.COLUMN_NAME = 'VERSION'
WHERE 1=1 
AND t.TABLE_NAME LIKE '%\_%'
AND t.TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE '%\_%'
AND BINARY(t.TABLE_NAME) != LOWER(t.TABLE_NAME)
```

Comment: Bad habits [you should learn to break A.S.A.P](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)
It's `YEAR(CURDATE())`, the **ANSI-92** explicit JOIN syntax has been around for `(YEAR(CURDATE() - 1992) as A_Very_Long_Time`, it's long past time you adopted it's use. 
Bad Habits to Kick : [Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: And throwing a rough guess as a bit of sample code does not show effort

Comment: Do you have any question about this query?

Comment: In case anyone is curious - if you run it, it returns no entity and has 0 column count.

Comment: No idea where you found that second bit of SQL from? But it does not do what you question asks, even if it ran

Comment: it does, need to add only group by.

Answer (score 2):

You're overcomplicating it.

```sql
SELECT TABLE_NAME, TABLE_SCHEMA, COUNT(*) COLUMNS
  FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
 GROUP BY  TABLE_NAME, TABLE_SCHEMA
```

You can add all sorts of WHERE clauses etc to this.

And, in StackOverflow it's good to explain what you tried, and what went wrong when you tried it.

Comment: This is pretty good, works, fast, and filled with brevity.

Answer (score -1):

I got the solution, if some one is looking for similar one,
Question: Get all the table names, and their column count across databases in mysql:

```
SELECT  CONCAT(t.TABLE_SCHEMA, '.', t.TABLE_NAME) as entity, 
count(c.COLUMN_NAME) FROM information_schema.TABLES t 
JOIN information_schema.STATISTICS s 
on s.TABLE_CATALOG = t.TABLE_CATALOG 
AND s.TABLE_SCHEMA = t.TABLE_SCHEMA 
AND s.TABLE_NAME = t.TABLE_NAME 
AND s.INDEX_NAME  = 'PRIMARY' 
AND s.COLUMN_NAME = 'PK' 
AND s.SEQ_IN_INDEX  = 1 
JOIN information_schema.`COLUMNS` c 
on c.TABLE_CATALOG = t.TABLE_CATALOG AND c.TABLE_SCHEMA = t.TABLE_SCHEMA AND c.TABLE_NAME = t.TABLE_NAME WHERE 1=1  AND BINARY(t.TABLE_NAME) != LOWER(t.TABLE_NAME) GROUP BY t.TABLE_NAME, t.TABLE_SCHEMA;
```

Comment: No that does not work! But the answer from O Jones does :)

Comment: Confirmed it also does not work when I tested it, at least the first version gave a count of 0, this version returns nothing when  I execute it.

Comment: it works 100%, I tested. it was expecting schema name should have _, but now I removed that also, try now.